# Publishing a java web application using Netbeans

Tags: web-applications, netbeans, jakarta-ee, publishing

Can you publish a Java web application to an instance of a running remote Tomcat/Glassfish or be it any J2EE app server from netbeans, similar to the way you publish a web application using VS? If yes, please provide the steps

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  You have to define the server in the "Services" tab of Netbeans, and indicate in the project settings that you want to run on that server.  Project settings are accessed by rightclicking the project in the the project pane, properties.  The target server can be found in the "run" branch of the settings tree.

Comment: This is possible if the server is a local installation. What if a server is up an running at a remote location and I need to publish my app on the remote instance?

Comment: You just need to add the remote server as a remote server in netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

That's at least possible with GlassFish v2. You have to have a local installation of GlassFish app server. Then, go to **Services** tab, **right-click** on **Servers**, click on **Add Server**:

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/82/picture1qhe.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/82/picture1qhe.png)

In the launched wizard, select **GlassFish v2**, click **Next**, then select the option **Register Remote Domain**, click **Next**, enter the name of the remote host and admin port number.

[alt text http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/6315/picture2gl.png](http://img196.imageshack.us/img196/6315/picture2gl.png)